# How to change a class's content using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here is the div element on my page:

How can I change a class's content?

So from existing which is: class="jcarousel-next jcarousel-next-horizontal"

to class="jcarousel-next jcarousel-next-horizontal jcarousel-next-
disabled jcarousel-next-disabled-horizontal"

Do I need to completely remove it by using removeClass and then re-add?

Comment: removeClass and addClass both work on single class names, that is, `removeClass('jcarousel-next')` *only* removes this class and leaves all others intact. Same with addClass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no you can just use addClass.  if you add a class that is already there jQuery wont add it again

```
$('#myelem').addClass('jcarousel-next-disabled jcarousel-next-disabled-horizontal');
```

Comment: choose this answer because it was put into context for me with an example..otherwise I get that it preserves it...ok but what does that mean to me in terms of use of this..I did not know that thus you can just override that class by specifying it's content like this.  This is part of why I hate open source documentation, too many inferred things after a one line sentence.

Answer (score 4):

The [`addClass`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/addClass) function preserves existing classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery('#myobj').removeClass('class-to-remove').addClass('class-to-add');
```

EDIT: multiple classes at once:

```
jQuery('#myobj').removeClass('class1 class2').addClass('class3 class4');
```

Also you can toggle classes with [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Brg.